# npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL when installing joi validation package

Tags: node.js, validation, npm, stack, mern

I’m trying to install *"joi"* validation package, but I still get `npm ERR!`  error.
I’m not under a proxy and tried running the following but it doesn't work:

```
npm i joi —-force
```

Answer (score 0):

joi take more resource or execution time to check validations, You can go with the custom validations..
else

```
npm install joi
```

this works for me

Comment: Thanks but it stills doesn’t work

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.